# Adjusting two "three part tables" side by side in a document

Tags: tables, formatting, article, booktabs, threeparttable

I am trying to put two "three part tables" side by side in a document using this TeX code:

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={7in, 10in}]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{threeparttable}


\begin{document}
    
\begin{table}[!htb]
    \setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
    \footnotesize
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.25}
    \begin{threeparttable}
        \begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}
            \centering
            
            \begin{tabular}{@{}
                    r S[table-format=-2.3] S[table-format=-2.3]
                    @{\hspace{12pt}} !{\vrule width 0.2pt} @{\hspace{12pt}}
                    r S[table-format=-2.3] S[table-format=-2.3]
                    @{}}
                \toprule
                \multicolumn{1}{c}{$r_h$} & $\omega_{Re}$ & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$\omega_{Im}$} &
                \multicolumn{1}{c}{$r_h$} & $\omega_{Re}$ & $\omega_{Im}$ \\
                \midrule[0.08cm]
                \multicolumn{6}{c}{\textbf{\textbf{$a=0.01 $ }}}\\

                ~       1 & 2.799 & -2.687 & 5 & 9.492 & -13.332 \\
                10 & 18.629 & -26.649 & 25 & 46.303 & -66.596 \\
                50    & 92.516 &-133.201  & 100   & 184.982 &-266.401 \\
                125   & 231.100 &-332.833  & 200   & 368.978&-531.432 \\
                225 & 415.166 & -597.962  & 300 & 555.017 & -799.401 \\
                
                \multicolumn{6}{c}{\textbf{$ a=0.1 $}} \\
                
                ~   1     &2.936    &-2.745   & 5     & 9.689   &-13.398 \\
                10    & 18.830  &-26.715  & 25    &46.505   &-66.671 \\
                50  & 92.718 & -133.266  & 100 & 185.178 & -266.459  \\
                125   & 231.411 &-333.055  & 200   & 370.115    &-532.844 \\
                225   & 416.349 &-599.439  & 300   & 555.056    &-799.231 \\
                
                \multicolumn{6}{c}{\textbf{\textbf{$a = 0.2$}}} \\
                
                ~   1     &3.091    &-2.809  & 5     & 9.906    &-13.470 \\
                10    & 19.052  &-26.788  & 25    & 46.729  &-66.744  \\
                50    & 92.942 &-133.340  & 100   & 185.402 &-266.532 \\
                125   &231.636  &-333.128  & 200   & 370.339    &-532.917  \\
                225   &416.574  &-599.513  & 300   &555.280 &-799.303 \\
                \bottomrule
            \end{tabular}
        \end{minipage}
        \hfill
        
        \begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}
            \centering
            
                \begin{tabular}{@{}
                        r S[table-format=-2.3] S[table-format=-2.3]
                        @{\hspace{12pt}} !{\vrule width 0.2pt} @{\hspace{12pt}}
                        r S[table-format=-2.3] S[table-format=-2.3]
                        @{}}
                    \toprule
                    \multicolumn{1}{c}{$r_h$} & $\omega_{Re}$ & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$\omega_{Im}$} &
                    \multicolumn{1}{c}{$r_h$} & $\omega_{Re}$ & $\omega_{Im}$ \\
                    \midrule[0.08cm]
                    \multicolumn{6}{c}{\textbf{\textbf{$a=0.01 $ }}}\\
                    
                    ~       1 &2.813 & -2.677 & 5 & 9.493 &-13.332 \\
                    10 &18.629 & -26.649 & 25 &46.303 &-66.605 \\
                    50 &92.516 &-133.201 & 100 & 184.982 & -266.401 \\
                    125 &231.100 &-332.833 & 200 & 368.978 &-531.432 \\
                    225 &415.166 &-597.962 & 300 & 555.017 &-799.303 \\
                
                    \multicolumn{6}{c}{\textbf{$ a=0.1 $}} \\
                    
                    ~       1 &2.949 &-2.736 & 5 & 9.690 & -13.398 \\
                    10 & 18.830 & -26.715 & 25 & 46.505 & -66.671\\
                    50 &92.718 & -133.266 & 100 & 185.178 & -266.459 \\
                    125 & 231.411 & -333.055 & 200 & 370.115&-532.844 \\
                    225 & 416.349 & -599.439 & 300 &555.056 &-799.401\\
                    
                    \multicolumn{6}{c}{\textbf{\textbf{$a = 0.2$}}} \\
                    
                    ~       1 &3.102 & -2.801 & 5 & 9.907 &-13.471 \\
                    10 & 19.052 & -26.788 & 25 &46.729 &-66.744 \\
                    50 &92.943 & -133.339 & 100 & 185.403 & -266.532 \\
                    125 & 231.636 &-333.129 & 200 & 370.339 &-532.917 \\
                    225 &416.574 &-599.513 & 300 & 555.280 &-799.303 \\
                    \bottomrule
                \end{tabular}
                
            \end{minipage}
        \end{threeparttable}
    \end{table}
    
\end{document}
```

But I am not able to get the desired result. Any help in this regard would be truly beneficial!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. It's perfectly ok to *upvote* an answer you find useful immediately. In contrast, the site guidelines strongly recommend holding off on *accepting* any particular answer for several hours, and maybe even a day or two. That way, you don't inadvertently discourage others from providing additional, and potentially even better, answers.

Comment: @Mico I will keep that in mind.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several issues with your code. In no particular order:

- You don't appear to be using the machinery of the `threeparttable` package at all. The three formal parts of a `threeparttable` environment are (a) a `tabular`-like environment, (b) a `\caption` directive, and (c) a `tablenotes` environment. Since there are no `\caption` directives and no `tablenotes` environmens, and since the `tabular` environments are encased in `minipage` environments and thus are *invisible* to the single `threeparttable` environment, it's basically doing nothing at all. Just omit it.
- The `minipage` environments don't seem to be doing anything useful either. I'd omit them as well.
- Nested `\textbf` directives -- as in `\textbf{\textbf{...}}` -- are pointless.
- The argument of a `\textbf` diretive should be text-mode material. Therefore, `\textbf{$a=0.01$}` is guaranteed to do nothing useful. Did you maybe mean to write `$\mathbf{a=0.01}$`, etc?
- The `S[table-format=-2.3]` column format specifications would all appear to be  wrong. Why not use either `S[table-format=3.3]` or `S[table-format=-3.3]`?
- I'd delete the vertical rules. They're not needed.
- The `\footnotesize` directive isn't needed either.
- Much of the material appears to require math mode. I suggest you use `array` instead of `tabular` environments and delete scores of `$` symbols, further reducing code clutter.
- Last but not least, don't leave blank lines between the two `tabular`/`array` environments.

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={7in, 10in}]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx} % for 'S' column type

% handy shortcut macros:
\newcommand\omegaRe{\omega_{\mkern1mu\mathrm{Re}}}
\newcommand\omegaIm{\omega_{\mkern1mu\mathrm{Im}}}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{table}[!htb]
    \setlength\arraycolsep{4pt} % default: 5pt
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.25}
         
    $\begin{array}[t]{@{}
    r S[table-format=3.3] S[table-format=-3.3]
    @{\hspace{25pt}}
    r S[table-format=3.3] S[table-format=-3.3]
    @{}}
     \toprule
     r_h & {\omegaRe} & {\omegaIm} & r_h & {\omegaRe} & {\omegaIm} \\
     \midrule
    
     \multicolumn{6}{c}{\mathbf{a=0.01}}\\
     1  &   2.799 &  -2.687 & 5   &   9.492 & -13.332 \\
     10 &  18.629 & -26.649 & 25  &  46.303 & -66.596 \\
     50 &  92.516 &-133.201 & 100 & 184.982 &-266.401 \\
     125& 231.100 &-332.833 & 200 & 368.978 &-531.432 \\
     225& 415.166 &-597.962 & 300 & 555.017 &-799.401 \\
     \addlinespace
     \multicolumn{6}{c}{\mathbf{a=0.1}} \\  
     1   &  2.936 &  -2.745 & 5   &   9.689 & -13.398 \\
     10  & 18.830 & -26.715 & 25  &  46.505 & -66.671 \\
     50  & 92.718 &-133.266 & 100 & 185.178 &-266.459 \\
     125 &231.411 &-333.055 & 200 & 370.115 &-532.844 \\
     225 &416.349 &-599.439 & 300 & 555.056 &-799.231 \\
     \addlinespace
     \multicolumn{6}{c}{\mathbf{a=0.2}} \\     
     1   &  3.091 &  -2.809 & 5   &   9.906 & -13.470 \\
     10  & 19.052 & -26.788 & 25  &  46.729 & -66.744 \\
     50  & 92.942 &-133.340 & 100 & 185.402 &-266.532 \\
     125 &231.636 &-333.128 & 200 & 370.339 &-532.917 \\
     225 &416.574 &-599.513 & 300 & 555.280 &-799.303 \\
     
     \bottomrule
     \end{array}$ 
     % don't leave a blank line
     \hfill       
     % don't leave a blank line
     $\begin{array}[t]{@{}
      r S[table-format=3.3] S[table-format=-3.3]
      @{\hspace{25pt}}
      r S[table-format=3.3] S[table-format=-3.3]
      @{}}
     \toprule
     r_h & {\omegaRe} & {\omegaIm} & r_h & {\omegaRe} & {\omegaIm} \\
     \midrule
      
      \multicolumn{6}{c}{\mathbf{a=0.01}}\\ 
      1   &  2.813 &  -2.677 & 5   &   9.493 & -13.332 \\
      10  & 18.629 & -26.649 & 25  &  46.303 & -66.605 \\
      50  & 92.516 &-133.201 & 100 & 184.982 &-266.401 \\
      125 &231.100 &-332.833 & 200 & 368.978 &-531.432 \\
      225 &415.166 &-597.962 & 300 & 555.017 &-799.303 \\
      \addlinespace
      \multicolumn{6}{c}{\mathbf{a=0.1}} \\
      1   &  2.949 &  -2.736 & 5   &   9.690 & -13.398 \\
      10  & 18.830 & -26.715 & 25  &  46.505 & -66.671 \\
      50  & 92.718 &-133.266 & 100 & 185.178 &-266.459 \\
      125 &231.411 &-333.055 & 200 & 370.115 &-532.844 \\
      225 &416.349 &-599.439 & 300 & 555.056 &-799.401 \\
      \addlinespace
      \multicolumn{6}{c}{\mathbf{a=0.2}} \\
      1   &  3.102 &  -2.801 & 5   &   9.907 & -13.471 \\
      10  & 19.052 & -26.788 & 25  &  46.729 & -66.744 \\
      50  & 92.943 &-133.339 & 100 & 185.403 &-266.532 \\
      125 &231.636 &-333.129 & 200 & 370.339 &-532.917 \\
      225 &416.574 &-599.513 & 300 & 555.280 &-799.303 \\
      
     \bottomrule
     \end{array}$

     \end{table}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for highlighting the errors in my code and simplifying it.

Answer (score 5):

Empty lines are end of paragraphs. If you want the tables side by side, you should not end a paragraph and start a new one. Removing the empty lines:

```latex
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={7in, 10in}]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{threeparttable}


\begin{document}
    
\begin{table}[!htb]
    \setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
    \footnotesize
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.25}
    \begin{threeparttable}
        \begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}
            \centering
            \begin{tabular}{@{}
                    r S[table-format=-2.3] S[table-format=-2.3]
                    @{\hspace{12pt}} !{\vrule width 0.2pt} @{\hspace{12pt}}
                    r S[table-format=-2.3] S[table-format=-2.3]
                    @{}}
                \toprule
                \multicolumn{1}{c}{$r_h$} & $\omega_{Re}$ & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$\omega_{Im}$} &
                \multicolumn{1}{c}{$r_h$} & $\omega_{Re}$ & $\omega_{Im}$ \\
                \midrule[0.08cm]
                \multicolumn{6}{c}{\textbf{\textbf{$a=0.01 $ }}}\\

                ~       1 & 2.799 & -2.687 & 5 & 9.492 & -13.332 \\
                10 & 18.629 & -26.649 & 25 & 46.303 & -66.596 \\
                50    & 92.516 &-133.201  & 100   & 184.982 &-266.401 \\
                125   & 231.100 &-332.833  & 200   & 368.978&-531.432 \\
                225 & 415.166 & -597.962  & 300 & 555.017 & -799.401 \\
                
                \multicolumn{6}{c}{\textbf{$ a=0.1 $}} \\
                
                ~   1     &2.936    &-2.745   & 5     & 9.689   &-13.398 \\
                10    & 18.830  &-26.715  & 25    &46.505   &-66.671 \\
                50  & 92.718 & -133.266  & 100 & 185.178 & -266.459  \\
                125   & 231.411 &-333.055  & 200   & 370.115    &-532.844 \\
                225   & 416.349 &-599.439  & 300   & 555.056    &-799.231 \\
                
                \multicolumn{6}{c}{\textbf{\textbf{$a = 0.2$}}} \\
                
                ~   1     &3.091    &-2.809  & 5     & 9.906    &-13.470 \\
                10    & 19.052  &-26.788  & 25    & 46.729  &-66.744  \\
                50    & 92.942 &-133.340  & 100   & 185.402 &-266.532 \\
                125   &231.636  &-333.128  & 200   & 370.339    &-532.917  \\
                225   &416.574  &-599.513  & 300   &555.280 &-799.303 \\
                \bottomrule
            \end{tabular}
        \end{minipage}%
        \hfill
        \begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}
            \centering
                \begin{tabular}{@{}
                        r S[table-format=-2.3] S[table-format=-2.3]
                        @{\hspace{12pt}} !{\vrule width 0.2pt} @{\hspace{12pt}}
                        r S[table-format=-2.3] S[table-format=-2.3]
                        @{}}
                    \toprule
                    \multicolumn{1}{c}{$r_h$} & $\omega_{Re}$ & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$\omega_{Im}$} &
                    \multicolumn{1}{c}{$r_h$} & $\omega_{Re}$ & $\omega_{Im}$ \\
                    \midrule[0.08cm]
                    \multicolumn{6}{c}{\textbf{\textbf{$a=0.01 $ }}}\\
                    
                    ~       1 &2.813 & -2.677 & 5 & 9.493 &-13.332 \\
                    10 &18.629 & -26.649 & 25 &46.303 &-66.605 \\
                    50 &92.516 &-133.201 & 100 & 184.982 & -266.401 \\
                    125 &231.100 &-332.833 & 200 & 368.978 &-531.432 \\
                    225 &415.166 &-597.962 & 300 & 555.017 &-799.303 \\
                
                    \multicolumn{6}{c}{\textbf{$ a=0.1 $}} \\
                    
                    ~       1 &2.949 &-2.736 & 5 & 9.690 & -13.398 \\
                    10 & 18.830 & -26.715 & 25 & 46.505 & -66.671\\
                    50 &92.718 & -133.266 & 100 & 185.178 & -266.459 \\
                    125 & 231.411 & -333.055 & 200 & 370.115&-532.844 \\
                    225 & 416.349 & -599.439 & 300 &555.056 &-799.401\\
                    
                    \multicolumn{6}{c}{\textbf{\textbf{$a = 0.2$}}} \\
                    
                    ~       1 &3.102 & -2.801 & 5 & 9.907 &-13.471 \\
                    10 & 19.052 & -26.788 & 25 &46.729 &-66.744 \\
                    50 &92.943 & -133.339 & 100 & 185.403 & -266.532 \\
                    125 & 231.636 &-333.129 & 200 & 370.339 &-532.917 \\
                    225 &416.574 &-599.513 & 300 & 555.280 &-799.303 \\
                    \bottomrule
                \end{tabular}
            \end{minipage}
        \end{threeparttable}
    \end{table}
    
\end{document}
```

results in:

[image: two tables side by side]

Comment: Such a silly mistake! Thanks, a lot :)

Answer (score 5):

I can't see how `threeparttable` would help for this job.

I'd simply use `tabular*` with appropriate dimensions as to leave a bit of horizontal space between the two tables; setting `\tabcolsep` to zero makes TeX do the job of computing the spaces.

I also fixed the column specification to comply with the actual data. If you want the cases to be printed in boldface, use `\boldmath`, rather than `\textbf` that does nothing to math.

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={7in, 10in}]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}


\begin{document}
    
\begin{table}[!htb]
%\footnotesize

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
\begin{tabular*}{0.48\textwidth}{
  @{\extracolsep{\fill}}
  S[table-format=3.0]
  S[table-format=3.3]
  S[table-format=-3.3]
  @{\qquad}
  S[table-format=3.0]
  S[table-format=-3.3]
  S[table-format=-3.3]
}
\toprule
{$r_h$} & {$\omega_{\mathrm{Re}}$} & {$\omega_{\mathrm{Im}}$} &
{$r_h$} & {$\omega_{\mathrm{Re}}$} & {$\omega_{\mathrm{Im}}$} \\
\midrule
\multicolumn{6}{c}{\boldmath$a=0.01$}\\
  1 &   2.799 &   -2.687 &   5 &   9.492 &  -13.332 \\
 10 &  18.629 &  -26.649 &  25 &  46.303 &  -66.596 \\
 50 &  92.516 & -133.201 & 100 & 184.982 & -266.401 \\
125 & 231.100 & -332.833 & 200 & 368.978 & -531.432 \\
225 & 415.166 & -597.962 & 300 & 555.017 & -799.401 \\
\addlinespace
\multicolumn{6}{c}{\boldmath$a=0.1$} \\
  1 &   2.936 &   -2.745 &   5 &   9.689 &  -13.398 \\
 10 &  18.830 &  -26.715 &  25 &  46.505 &  -66.671 \\
 50 &  92.718 & -133.266 & 100 & 185.178 & -266.459 \\
125 & 231.411 & -333.055 & 200 & 370.115 & -532.844 \\
225 & 416.349 & -599.439 & 300 & 555.056 & -799.231 \\
\addlinespace
\multicolumn{6}{c}{\boldmath$a = 0.2$} \\
  1 &   3.091 &   -2.809 &   5 &   9.906 &  -13.470 \\
 10 &  19.052 &  -26.788 &  25 &  46.729 &  -66.744 \\
 50 &  92.942 & -133.340 & 100 & 185.402 & -266.532 \\
125 & 231.636 & -333.128 & 200 & 370.339 & -532.917 \\
225 & 416.574 & -599.513 & 300 & 555.280 & -799.303 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}\hfill
\begin{tabular*}{0.48\textwidth}{
  @{\extracolsep{\fill}}
  S[table-format=3.0]
  S[table-format=3.3]
  S[table-format=-3.3]
  @{\qquad}
  S[table-format=3.0]
  S[table-format=-3.3]
  S[table-format=-3.3]
}
\toprule
{$r_h$} & {$\omega_{\mathrm{Re}}$} & {$\omega_{\mathrm{Im}}$} &
{$r_h$} & {$\omega_{\mathrm{Re}}$} & {$\omega_{\mathrm{Im}}$} \\
\midrule
\multicolumn{6}{c}{\boldmath$a=0.01$} \\
  1 &   2.813 &   -2.677 &   5 &   9.493 &  -13.332 \\
 10 &  18.629 &  -26.649 &  25 &  46.303 &  -66.605 \\
 50 &  92.516 & -133.201 & 100 & 184.982 & -266.401 \\
125 & 231.100 & -332.833 & 200 & 368.978 & -531.432 \\
225 & 415.166 & -597.962 & 300 & 555.017 & -799.303 \\
\addlinespace
\multicolumn{6}{c}{\boldmath$a=0.1$} \\
  1 &   2.949 &   -2.736 &   5 &   9.690 &  -13.398 \\
 10 &  18.830 &  -26.715 &  25 &  46.505 &  -66.671 \\
 50 &  92.718 & -133.266 & 100 & 185.178 & -266.459 \\
125 & 231.411 & -333.055 & 200 & 370.115 & -532.844 \\
225 & 416.349 & -599.439 & 300 & 555.056 & -799.401 \\
\addlinespace
\multicolumn{6}{c}{\boldmath$a = 0.2$} \\
  1 &   3.102 &   -2.801 &   5 &   9.907 &  -13.471 \\
 10 &  19.052 &  -26.788 &  25 &  46.729 &  -66.744 \\
 50 &  92.943 & -133.339 & 100 & 185.403 & -266.532 \\
125 & 231.636 & -333.129 & 200 & 370.339 & -532.917 \\
225 & 416.574 & -599.513 & 300 & 555.280 & -799.303 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}

\caption{Here is a caption for the side-by-side tables}

\end{table}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to add subcaptions:

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={7in, 10in}]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{table}[!htb]

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}

\begin{subtable}{0.48\textwidth}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{
  @{\extracolsep{\fill}}
  S[table-format=3.0]
  S[table-format=3.3]
  S[table-format=-3.3]
  @{\qquad}
  S[table-format=3.0]
  S[table-format=-3.3]
  S[table-format=-3.3]
}
\toprule
{$r_h$} & {$\omega_{\mathrm{Re}}$} & {$\omega_{\mathrm{Im}}$} &
{$r_h$} & {$\omega_{\mathrm{Re}}$} & {$\omega_{\mathrm{Im}}$} \\
\midrule
\multicolumn{6}{c}{\boldmath$a=0.01$}\\
  1 &   2.799 &   -2.687 &   5 &   9.492 &  -13.332 \\
 10 &  18.629 &  -26.649 &  25 &  46.303 &  -66.596 \\
 50 &  92.516 & -133.201 & 100 & 184.982 & -266.401 \\
125 & 231.100 & -332.833 & 200 & 368.978 & -531.432 \\
225 & 415.166 & -597.962 & 300 & 555.017 & -799.401 \\
\addlinespace
\multicolumn{6}{c}{\boldmath$a=0.1$} \\
  1 &   2.936 &   -2.745 &   5 &   9.689 &  -13.398 \\
 10 &  18.830 &  -26.715 &  25 &  46.505 &  -66.671 \\
 50 &  92.718 & -133.266 & 100 & 185.178 & -266.459 \\
125 & 231.411 & -333.055 & 200 & 370.115 & -532.844 \\
225 & 416.349 & -599.439 & 300 & 555.056 & -799.231 \\
\addlinespace
\multicolumn{6}{c}{\boldmath$a = 0.2$} \\
  1 &   3.091 &   -2.809 &   5 &   9.906 &  -13.470 \\
 10 &  19.052 &  -26.788 &  25 &  46.729 &  -66.744 \\
 50 &  92.942 & -133.340 & 100 & 185.402 & -266.532 \\
125 & 231.636 & -333.128 & 200 & 370.339 & -532.917 \\
225 & 416.574 & -599.513 & 300 & 555.280 & -799.303 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}

\caption{Subcaption}
\end{subtable}\hfill
\begin{subtable}{0.48\textwidth}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}
  @{\extracolsep{\fill}}
  S[table-format=3.0]
  S[table-format=3.3]
  S[table-format=-3.3]
  @{\qquad}
  S[table-format=3.0]
  S[table-format=-3.3]
  S[table-format=-3.3]
}
\toprule
{$r_h$} & {$\omega_{\mathrm{Re}}$} & {$\omega_{\mathrm{Im}}$} &
{$r_h$} & {$\omega_{\mathrm{Re}}$} & {$\omega_{\mathrm{Im}}$} \\
\midrule
\multicolumn{6}{c}{\boldmath$a=0.01$} \\
  1 &   2.813 &   -2.677 &   5 &   9.493 &  -13.332 \\
 10 &  18.629 &  -26.649 &  25 &  46.303 &  -66.605 \\
 50 &  92.516 & -133.201 & 100 & 184.982 & -266.401 \\
125 & 231.100 & -332.833 & 200 & 368.978 & -531.432 \\
225 & 415.166 & -597.962 & 300 & 555.017 & -799.303 \\
\addlinespace
\multicolumn{6}{c}{\boldmath$a=0.1$} \\
  1 &   2.949 &   -2.736 &   5 &   9.690 &  -13.398 \\
 10 &  18.830 &  -26.715 &  25 &  46.505 &  -66.671 \\
 50 &  92.718 & -133.266 & 100 & 185.178 & -266.459 \\
125 & 231.411 & -333.055 & 200 & 370.115 & -532.844 \\
225 & 416.349 & -599.439 & 300 & 555.056 & -799.401 \\
\addlinespace
\multicolumn{6}{c}{\boldmath$a = 0.2$} \\
  1 &   3.102 &   -2.801 &   5 &   9.907 &  -13.471 \\
 10 &  19.052 &  -26.788 &  25 &  46.729 &  -66.744 \\
 50 &  92.943 & -133.339 & 100 & 185.403 & -266.532 \\
125 & 231.636 & -333.129 & 200 & 370.339 & -532.917 \\
225 & 416.574 & -599.513 & 300 & 555.280 & -799.303 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}

\caption{Subcaption}
\end{subtable}

\caption{Here is a caption for the side-by-side tables}

\end{table}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for valuable tips. It definitely helped me a lot !